# Vagrant up return 403 Forbidden error when installing ansible

Tags: ansible, vagrant, yum, vagrantfile

When I run vagrant up on my Centos6, it shows this error:

> ==> w3package_v2: Running provisioner: ansible_local...
> w3package_v2: Installing Ansible...
> The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
> Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
>
> ```
> sudo rpm -i https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-`rpm >-E %dist | sed -n 's/.*el\ 
> ([0-9]\).*/\1/p'`.noarch.rpm
>
> Stdout from the command:
>
> Stderr from the command:
>
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
> error: skipping https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
> ```

Below is Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
APP_NAME = "w3package_v2"
VM_NAME = "w3package_v2"
GUEST_IP = "192.168.33.59"

# [note]
#   * for VirtualBox users:
#     vagrant-vbguest plugin required.
#     Run `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`.
#   * for Windows10 + Hyper-V users:
#     Enable SMB 1.0 (for Windows 10 + Hyper-V users)
if !Object.const_defined?('VagrantVbguest') || !Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-vbguest')
  puts "ERROR: vagrant-vbguest plugin is required. Run `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`."
  abort
end

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.define VM_NAME
  config.vm.box = "bento/centos-6"
  config.vm.boot_timeout = 3600

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: GUEST_IP
  config.vm.network :public_network, bridge: 'en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)'

  if OS.windows?
    config.vm.synced_folder ((File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../../..")).gsub("/","\\")), "/var/www/" + APP_NAME + "/current", owner: "vagrant", type: "virtualbox", automount: true, SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate: true
  else
    config.vm.synced_folder "../../../..", "/var/www/" + APP_NAME + "/current", id: "vagrant", nfs: true
  end

  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.name = VM_NAME
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap", "100"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled", 0]
    if OS.windows?
      vb.customize ["sharedfolder", "add", :id, "--name", VM_NAME, "--hostpath", (("//?/" + File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../../..")).gsub("/","\\"))]
      vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/" + VM_NAME, "1"]
      config.vm.provision "shell", path: "../../configuration/vagrant-vbmount.sh", args: VM_NAME
    end
  end

  config.vm.provider :hyperv do |h, override|
    h.enable_virtualization_extensions = true
    h.linked_clone = true
    override.vm.synced_folder ((File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../../..")).gsub("/","\\")), "/var/www/" + APP_NAME + "/current", type: "smb", automount: true, SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate: true
  end
  config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.limit = "all"
    ansible.compatibility_mode = "2.0"
    ansible.playbook = "/var/www/" + APP_NAME + "/current/tools/provisioning/configuration/vagrant-local.yml"
    ansible.verbose = "v"
  end
end

## ref https://qiita.com/dd511805/items/8cb7e524e0d790c24af1
module OS
  def OS.windows?
    (/cygwin|mswin|mingw|bccwin|wince|emx/ =~ RUBY_PLATFORM) != nil
  end
end
```

And this is my main.yml file:

```
- name: check dir /var/www
  shell: '[ -e /var/www ]; echo $?'
  register: result

- name: mkdir /var/www
  command: mkdir /var/www
  when: result.stdout != '0'

- name: change locale
  shell: 'cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Japan /etc/localtime'

- name: install python-selinux
  yum: pkg=libselinux-python state=latest

- name: disable selinux
  selinux: state=disabled

- name: install epel-repo
  yum: pkg=epel-release state=latest

- name: fix CentOS-Base.repo
  template: src=CentOS-Base.repo dest=/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

- name: update yum
  yum: name=* state=latest
```

How could I fix that?

Comment: Well, can you fetch that .rpm manually? Because otherwise automation is just designed to automate things that one could do by hand. Also, your experience with ansible will be worlds better if you learn the modules and don't attempt to have "a shell script in yaml" -- it took you 4 lines to recreate `- file: path=/var/www state=directory`